# C++ decimal points

Tags: c++

I have this function:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>
double SimplifiedExample () {
  setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
  char txt [] = "3.14";
  for (int x=0; txt [x]; x++) 
    if (txt [x] == '.')
      txt [x] = localeconv ()->decimal_point [0];

  char *endptr;
  return strtod (txt, &endptr);
}
```

This works on every Windows 10 and Linux system I've tried it on. It fails on at least one Windows 7 machine (which reports "," for localeconv ()->decimal_point [0], but uses "." in both sprintf and strtod). Is the use of localeconv to supply the system decimal point to strtod correct, or not?

Note that I can't remove the setlocale() call. The application MUST respect locale settings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571359/how-do-i-set-the-proper-initial-locale-for-a-c-program-on-windows and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale -- you start in C locale by default, if you want to honor the user's locale, you have to set it explicitly.

Comment: locale handling in standard C/C++ sucks. It is hard to use and inconsistent between platforms. I recommend search libraries which could do that. Also you are asking question as "fix my solution" not "I have this task how to do it, I'm trying this". So on some level your question suffers from [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: As I said: the application respects the locale setting of the environment (so it displays decimal points, thousands separators, dates, etc. in the format selected by the user of the system). I was not asking about how to do that, it's just the context in which the application runs, and the reason why strtod requires a non-default decimal point.

Comment: I'm cathegorically not asking to "fix my solution". I am trying to understand whether localeconv()->decimal_point, sprintf(), and strtod() will all use the same decimal point character or not.

Comment: How do you read data? From file `std::ifstream`, `fscanf` or some Windows specific API? From user (standard input)? Or do you need read data from some string? Can you show some code? Did you setup global locale for C and C++? Or you do not want to change global locale of application? What is the encoding used by system?

Comment: I honestly don't see how I read the data is in any way relevant. It comes from a Postgres database, if you really care. After I've read it, I iterate over the read characters, replacing dots by the system decimal point (as obtained from localeconv), before passing it into strtod. The problem is that strtod does not recognize the system decimal point from localeconv as the decimal point. The question is whether I misunderstood what localeconv is supposed to mean.

Comment: For example you can set locale on specific C++ stream and then conversion is done by stream. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue if you set global locale behavior of many functions also changes.

Comment: I've added a code sample and removed everything else since it apparently only confuses people.

Comment: Windows 7, Windows 10 - this appears to be a common mistake by Unix/Linux programmers. You're not interacting directly with the OS, you're using a C++ compiler and C++ libraries. And MinGW has radically different ideas than Visual Studio. In comparison, the exact OS version is much less important. Windows does not consider any C++ library to be part of the OS.

Comment: Fair enough. The compiler for the Windows versions is MSVC2019.

Comment: @H.Guijt: The question is probably a bit ambiguous. Do you really mean the **system** decimal point? Because on Windows, **user** settings override the **system** settings. `GetUserDefaultLocaleName ` is not necessarily the same as `GetSystemDefaultLocaleName`, for instance.

Comment: I do not get it what is your problem. This code sample doesn't make sense at leas it doesn't show what is your actual problem. Here is [example how locale can be used in C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7871abe6aed32b9). Note coliru by default uses "C" locale so I'm forcing "cs_CZ.utf8" locale where coma is used as decimal separator (and space as thousands separator)..

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried "man strtod"? I have Slackware linux and the strtod man page has strtod, which mentions locale for the decimal point, and says it lives in stdlib.h.

Comment: The man page for strtod only informs us that the decimal point is locale dependent, nothing more. I know I used a lot of words, but could you at least read the question before writing some throwaway answer that doesn't help at all?

Comment: `man std::strtod` won't work. That should be a hint; you're trying to give a C answer to a C++ question. `<cstdlib>` is the correct C++ header.

Answer (score -2):

You're falling into a bog of implementation defined behaviour.

The problem might be in that the `setlocale` on Windows doesn't behave how it is proposed in standards, due to it being a library wrapper around OS's idiosincrazie, e.g. UTF-8 supported in C++ runtime only in Win10. More of, some C++ library implementations of sprintf\printf\strtod respects only `std::locale::global`. More of, some runtimes do not support anything but "C" and "" and formatted output only ANSI or IEEE-754 (hence , a dot). Old Win10 and older versions do not even respect IEEE-754.

E.g, an arbitrary MinGW64 on Windows-7 would respond to this code:

```
 auto old_locale = std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
 cout << old_locale.name() << "\n";
 cout << std::locale("").name() << "\n";
```

with reporting an ANSI locale

```
 C
 C
```

output regardless of system locale and doesn't recognize OEM locale ".OCP" or any present locale name. This behaviour is hard-coded in library linked with application,not in some system-wide one.

Note that you can try check returned value of setlocale:

```
auto loc = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
if (loc == NULL){
   printf ("setlocale failed!\n");
}
else
    printf ("setlocale %s!\n",loc );
```

And in my case it had returned... "English_United States.1252" while I have a US locale set for user and "Russian_Russia.1251" for russian user locale, which doesn't match more usual "En-US" format. Windows uses underscores.

There would be another problem to solve while interfacing with some database service which would be run as a different user. Existing databases already implement support in defining what locale the particular database uses.

More of output of all library functions didn't change with the change of locale.

Developers of multiplatform applications are urged to use proper library packages for formatted input\output which would eliminate the struggle with platform and implementation specific behaviour.

Comment: Can you give an example or even better a recommendation for a "proper library package" that handles locale correctly?

Comment: @H.Guijt you may look at ICU. if you use some framework libraries, they may already include support for ICU in them, e.g. Qt or OSG.

Comment: This is not correct. It  starts off wrong: "`setlocale` on Windows...". That's a UNIX//Linux mistake. Windows has no `setlocale` function. It does have `SetThreadLocale`, but that's significantly different. Each C++ library on Windows will need to decide how it handles that conceptual difference. The comments state that Visual Studio is used, so we should check its documentation.

Comment: @MSalters yes it, have, it's a macro expanding to a family of functions depending on  settings, it links into runtime. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-160. Also OP talks about attempting to make it work on a legacy platform, it behaved more erratic there. The misconception that there is no `setlocale` led to that mingw\migw64 had rolled own versions of it which doesn't affect MS runtime.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: MSDN holds both the documentation of Windows (the OS) and Visual Studio (one of the C++ compilers for Windows). The link you gave literally ends in `msvc-160` - it's explicitly dependent on the compiler version, not the OS version.

Comment: @MSalters  Depends on both actually,  this behaviour changes with OS because they rely on API. Strictly speaking so are `printf`,`strtod`, etc., those all functions are also a part of runtime library, not of API.OS supplied with certain runtime version by default, compiler provides SxS alternatives. By this logic "there is no printf on Windows". implementation defined behaviour covers it